# SSJS debugger slow to start

Tags: debugging, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

IBM Domino 9
Local server.

Every XPage loads extremely slow when the debugger is enabled in the IBM Domino Designer client. When not enabled the XPage loads in <1s, but when it's enabled >30s.

That would be tolerable if the debugger would start while I'm still, reasonably, young.. But it takes forever as well.

Feels like something has to time out before the debugger starts and stops on my brake point.

Any ideas?

/J

Comment: Have you increased memory for server and designer? The debugger communicates on its own port. Any AV getting into the way?

Comment: Windows 8.1 64Bit, Domino 9.0 64Bit 16GB - notes.ini: HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize=512M, jvm.properties: vmarg.Xmx=-Xmx1024m vmarg.Xms=-Xms512m vmarg.Xmca=-Xmca512k

Comment: No, AV that I'm aware of. It's the same issues on both of my machines.